# Brut Force "Subarray Product Less Than K"

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, brute-force

I am trying to solve this problem using recursion getting all the contiguous subarrays and then checking

> Your are given an array of positive integers nums . Count and print
>   the number of (contiguous) subarrays where the product of all the
>   elements in the subarray is less than k

At this point I wrote this part of code :

```
def product_arr(array):
    counter = 1
    for i in range(len(array)):
        counter *= array[i]
    return counter


def numSubArray(array, k):
    if len(array) == 0:
        return 0
    if product_arr(array) <= k:
        return 1
    res_1 = numSubArray(array[1:], k//array[0])
    res_2 = numSubArray(array[:-1], k//array[-1])

    return 1 + res_1 + res_2
```

But It is not working ...
It is printing now '15' instead of '8' for  :

```
arr = [10, 5, 2, 6]
print(numSubArray(arr, 100))
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I think in your example, the correct answer is 9, btw:

All 4 length 1 arrays work. All 3 length 2 arrays work. All 2 length 3 arrays work. The length 4 array doesn't work. So 4 + 3 + 2 = 9.

Answer (score 2):

It often helps if you spell out in plain English (or whatever language you are most comfortable with) what you think the recursion relation looks like, and I'm reasonably sure that your recursion idea is wrong. What you have written is this:

1. In an empty array, there are no subarrays (but you return `None` instead of `0`. Why?
2. If the product of all the numbers in the array is less than `k`, the number of sub arrays is 1.
3. Otherwise it's the number of subarrays if we'd drop the first item, plus the number of subarrays if we'd drop the second item.

There's something wrong in all 3 of these points. First, in 1. you should return 0 instead of "nothing". An empty array has no contiguous subarrays, so "0" is the correct answer.

Now for number 2. Your `return 1` makes it so that the other line, `return res1 + res2` never gets executed. Clearly that can't be your intention, but it explains why you get the answer `2` in the end: In your example, the full array doesn't satisfy the `<= k` test, so we return the `res1 + res2`, and those will most certainly be both 1.

The fix for *that* piece of logic is: Instead of returning 1, you'd return `1 + res1 + res2'.

So now let's examine your recursion logic:

You say "To count all the contiguous subarrays of a given array so that their product is less than k, we first count all the contiguous subarrays of that array that don't include the array's first element. Then we count all the contiguous subarrays of that array that don't include the array's last element. We add those two numbers up, and finally, we check if the product of the total array is less than or equal k and add 1 if that's the case".

The problem with that recursion logic is that you'll be double-counting some arrays, in the "middle" of your array! Those contain neither the first nor the last element!

You're thinking in the right direction though! This "everything but the first" and "everything but the last" sort of recursion pops up here and there in comp sci and math. The trick is that you need to adjust things a bit to "force" your formulation to take the first element into account:

What we *want* is: Given my array, how many appropriate contiguous subarrays are there that definitely contain the first element, but definitely don't contain the last element? And how many contiguous subarrays are there that definitely contain the last element, but definitely don't contain the first element?

You've already got the "don't contain the first/last" element part right, with the array indices. Now how do we "force" it to contain the first element? By *also* dropping it from the indices and adjusting k accordingly.

Here is an example of what I mean:

How many contiguous subarrays satisfy the condition of `[10, 5, 2, 6]` with `k = 100` so that they contain the `10` but don't contain the `6`?

Exactly as many as there's contiguous subarrays that satisfy the condition of `[5, 2]` with `k = 10`. Basically, by dropping the 10 from the array and dividing `k` by `10` we say: "Oh yeah we're definitely picking the 10, so we must adjust the `k` accordingly".

So then in your recursion, in *both* cases it will be `array[1:-1]` and `k` replaced by `k / array[0]` or `k / array[-1]` (make sure to pick the correct one, and spend some time thinking about integer division and rounding, which I am leaving as an exercise for you :p )

That should get you well on your way of solving it, but now here's an extra trick to speed things up. Quick question, without too much thinking, how many contiguous subarrays of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,]` have a product smaller than 1000? Answer: ALL OF THEM. So if you compute the product of the array first, and it is smaller than `k`, you don't need to do a brute force recursion any more! You "just" need to compute the total number of these contiguous subarrays! Depending on your background, that's a simple combinatorial problem.

---

EDIT: Some more thinking :)
Okay let's think about solving this. First, if you *really* want to do brute force, you just have to create every possible contiguous subarray and check its product:

```py
count = 0
for start in range(0, len(array)):
  for end in range(start+1, len(array)):
    if product_arr(array[start:end]) <= k:
      count += 1
```

The runtime of that is unfortunately O(N^3), because you essentially have three nested loops.

What this all reminds me of is largest sum contiguous subarray problem: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray/

This can be solved in O(N), and I think the general idea can be used here as well, but instead of keeping track of the maximum, you keep track of the number of subarrays that "work", and you do so in a smart way...

You'd run a loop with a "start of the subarray" and then inside another loop with the "end of the subarray". You keep increasing the end by 1 and check if adding that extra integer to your product keeps you below "k". If it does, you keep going, and you increase your subarray count by "end - start + 1". This is the crucial trick to speed things up. Basically, you're counting not just the one newly identified subarray, you're also counting all the other subarrays that you'd get by dropping the first, second, third, etc. element. Because if a * b * c <= k for positive integers a, b, c, then obviously also b * c <= k and c <= k.

This is a bit tricky to figure out the boundaries and exact details, but I can't help you with that.

Comment: Thank You , I update my post but I have some question : why it needs to be array[1:-1] and why the " 1 + " in the final return change the way of returning the value ? Thank you again for your clear explanation

Comment: The updated code doesn't quite follow what I said. The `return 1` is definitely wrong. When you have your `res1 + res2`, then you _add_ 1 if the product of the whole array is `<= k` and you don't add 1 if it's not.

Now thinking about it, the recursion I talk about is still wrong... I think splitting the recursion into two parts is what makes it too hard logically.

Comment: There is no way or getting at least all the contiguous subarray without duplicates ?